# phpMyAdmin: issue with creating a column after existing 28 columns

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a MySQL table that contains a 28 columns, now whenever I create another column it does get created; but I can't see it when I go at **phpmyadmin main table page**. in other words when I try to insert a new row, and when I start filling the data, I see the new column (that I created before) but after inserting the row and go to main table page… I don't see the whole column. I tried changing the view limit from the sql query, but nothing.

So I have some questions:

> 1. Is there a limitation of creating columns?
> 2. Did i cross the maximum allowed space (if there's a maximum space)
> 3. What the heck is wrong?

P.S: I tried re-ordering the columns so I moved the column to the first place, but the last column got disappeared!

Comment: Are you using phpmyAdmin?

Comment: On main page of what?

Comment: The main page of PhpMyAdmin ( the page when you see all table data )

Comment: [Aside] Why are you creating more and more columns?

Comment: @Strawberry I'm using mysql to store players data on gaming servers so its quite different from web usage; in gaming servers you will need a huge amount of columns to store their data.

Comment: The effects of column limits are usually more implicit than explicit.... technically 4096 columns is the column limit. But typically folks bump against the row limit before that. Do note that these limits can vary depending on a number of factors (DBA settings, host settings, storage engine, etc). you can read more about that here. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/column-count-limit.html  In terms of what the heck is wrong, you probably need to add some additional info... what types of columns are these? Have you done basic troubleshooting (refreshing page, not using back button, etc)?

Comment: Well i have: 13 int(11), 3 float and 12 varchar with different lengths. anyways, what kind of additional info you mean. like engine type? and i tried the troubleshooting that i could like re-organizing the columns, renaming the columns, changing the length and types of the columns, refreshing the page one million time. i actually created a new table with the same columns and i inserted one row for testing.. then i created another column, and when submitting.. i received an error message that says "error in processing request error code:200" and "table .. has been altered successfully"

Comment: Which phpMyAdmin version? Which browser?

Comment: @MarcDelisle I use phpMyAdmin version 4.0.9 hosted on local server / chrome. currently i'm working on the new table that i made, but what caused that problem?

Comment: Is your server running Suhosin?  and have you tried with the recent phpMyAdmin 4.1.13 version?